# Ajax call returning undefined using symfony2.3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony-2.3

I'm getting an undefined return from an ajax call and I don't know what's wrong. 
Here's the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                async:false,
                url: "{{ path('home_volcado_ajax') }}",
                statusCode: {
                    200: function(f) {
                        $('#volcado-container').append( '<strong>' + f.fechaVolcado + '</strong>' );
                    }
                },
                complete: function() {
                    loading = false;
                }
            });
        });
```

The thing is I get the value `fechaVolcado` correctly when checking the network response traffic from the browser `{ "fechaVolcado" : 30-12-2013 13:01:27 }` so the controller method is fine. The error must come when I get the response from the method `volcado.json`.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug! it was simply a parse error. If you look carefully, the response of the controller was { "fechaVolcado" : 30-12-2013 13:01:27 } and all it needed was change the response from this 30-12-2013 13:01:27 to this "30-12-2013 13:01:27" (with quotation marks) so I changed my controller response to this:

return $jsonResponse->setStatusCode(200)->setContent('{ "fechaVolcado" : "' . $fecha . '" }');

and it worked!!!

It was a newie mistake, still it took large amount of time.

Thank you!